# Will the fact that you traveled to Pakistan be a problem if you go to India?

Tags: passports, india, pakistan

As I understand it India and Pakistan are at war. I have a bucket list dream to go to all three the nations on the Indian sub-continent.

Is it going to be a problem if I go to India and they see a Pakistani stamp in my passport?

Comment: It appears the land Wagah-Attari border is open, if that's the case I don't think it would be a problem, especially if you enter by air

Comment: If you are British, sometimes the British government will issue a 2nd passport so that you can visit conflicting countries.  I'm not sure how compelling your reasons need to be.

Comment: If India & Pakistan are in an actual shooting war at present, Google News doesn't appear to know about it.

Comment: @SimonCrase it's not a shooting war; it's more of a cold war. No peace treaty has ever been signed. Only repeated ceasefires. Nonetheless, crossing from one to the other is possible.

Comment: @Stewart AFAIK many countries offer the possibility of a second passport. For example after visiting Israel. The authorities know that a passport stamp can compromise one's future travel. It's considered a legitimate reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this applies only to citizens (and those that have origin) from Pakistan/India. There are enough people (eg: Karl Rock) that have done what you propose to do.